# Random selection of a percent of entries from a table

Tags: php, ms-access

I’m try to get a random selection of 30% of tickets in a bin. The below code works for the 30%, but when I add “ORDER BY RND(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID)” to the end, I get an error.

Works:

```
$result1 = "SELECT MainBin.Assignee, Count(MainBin.IncidentNumber) * .3 AS CountOfIncidentNumber FROM  MainBin GROUP BY MainBin.Assignee";
$rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$result1);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs1))
{
$Assignee = "". $row['Assignee'];
$CountOfIncidentNumber = ceil($row["CountOfIncidentNumber"]);
$result2 = "INSERT INTO TicketBin (IncidentNumber)
SELECT TOP $CountOfIncidentNumber IncidentNumber FROM MainBin 
WHERE Assignee = '$Assignee'";
$rs2=odbc_exec($conn,$result2);
}
```

Does Not Work:

```
 $result1 = "SELECT MainBin.Assignee, Count(MainBin.IncidentNumber) * .3 AS CountOfIncidentNumber FROM  MainBin GROUP BY MainBin.Assignee ORDER BY RND(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID)";
 $rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$result1);
```

I have and AutoNumber field named ID and I’ve used this before, just not with the grouping.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you "get an error" you mean the error

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'RND(INT(NOW()*ID)-NOW()*ID)' as part of an aggregate function.

then you could try using an approach like this

```sql
SELECT
        Assignee,
        CountOfIncidentNumber
FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                    MainBin.Assignee, 
                    COUNT(MainBin.IncidentNumber) * .3 AS CountOfIncidentNumber,
                    MIN(ID) AS MinOfID
            FROM MainBin 
            GROUP BY MainBin.Assignee
        )
ORDER BY RND(INT(NOW*MinOfID)-NOW*MinOfID)
```

### Edit re: comment

It sounds like perhaps you need to keep your original code and just use this instead:

```
$result2 = "INSERT INTO TicketBin (IncidentNumber)
SELECT TOP $CountOfIncidentNumber IncidentNumber FROM MainBin 
WHERE Assignee = '$Assignee' ORDER BY RND(INT(NOW*ID)-NOW*ID)";
```

Comment: That randomized the order of the same 30% as before.  That made me realize I may be asking the wrong question.  For example, an Assignee has 19 total tickets in the MainBin. I want 30%, (6 tickets) to be selected at random from MainBin and inserted into TicketBin.